# Azure Data Factory - Dynamic host name in FTP Linked Service

Tags: ftp, azure-data-factory

All,
Please pardon me if this is a trivial query. I am using FTP linked service in ADF and I need to use the FTP host name dynamically. I need to work on hundreds of FTP servers and creating hundreds of linked services is definitely not a good idea.

In most of the linked services, there is an option of dynamic content but for FTP linked service I don't see it. Is there a way that I could pass the FTP host name dynamically thus avoid creating hundreds of linked services.

Thanks for your help on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can do it specifying dynamic contents in JSON Format:**

[image: SFTP Linked Service Example]

**Here is the Json code that allows for dynamic linked service parameters:**

```
{
    "properties": {
        "type": "sftp",
        "parameters": {
            "HostName": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": ""
            },
            "UserName": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": ""
            },
            "Port": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": ""
            },
            "SecretName": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": ""
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "host": "@linkedService().HostName",
            "userName": "@linkedService().UserName",
            "port": "@linkedService().Port",
            "skipHostKeyValidation": true,
            "authenticationType": "Basic",
            "password": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "KEYVAULT_Ops",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "@linkedService().SecretName"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The important part here is the first part:**

```
"parameters": {
            "HostName": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": ""
            },
            "UserName": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": ""
            },
            "Port": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": ""
            },
            "SecretName": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": ""
            }
        },
```

**You can then reference these parameters in the json like this:**
[image: LinkedService Parameter example]

**This is what it looks like when creating the dataset for that linked service:**
[image: Dataset Illustration showing Linked Service Parameters]

Comment: FYI, this WILL work with FTP Linked Service as well, though I used a SFTP example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saves me tons of time. It feels great when someone helps you promptly. I realized, this code is very similar to ARM templates. To share,  I changed the "type": "FtpServer". Thanks again. It means a lot to me.

Comment: No problem, here to help :)