# Azure Data Factory : Add timeout to Sftp Linked Service

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way to specify the timeout of an Sftp Linked Service on Azure Data Factory? I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728208/azure-data-factory-dynamic-host-name-in-ftp-linked-service) mentioning custom properties via json but not finding a timeout setting. 
In the copy activity there is a 7 days timeout but when I have a sftp source(as seen in the image below), it takes approx 5 to 7 mins to timeout. Is there a way to reduce this to a minute?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You can manage the Timeout at the activity level (like Copy or GetMetadata), but I do not think you can define it at the Linked Service level.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of where you would set the timeout:

[image: Timeout Activity Example]